# How do I hide this prod-cat-desc div if empty

Tags: php, jquery

Since some of my shop products have long descriptions I have set a min-height in my css, however, some products have no description, so I'd like to just hide the div if it is empty.

```
//Display product category descriptions under category image/title on woocommerce shop page */
//remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', 'ig_add_cat_description', 15);
function ig_add_cat_description ($category) {
$cat_id=$category->term_id;
$prod_term=get_term($cat_id,'product_cat');
$description=$prod_term->description;
echo '<div class="shop_cat_desc">'.$description.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Display product category descriptions under category image/title on woocommerce shop page */ 
//remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', 'ig_add_cat_description', 15);
function ig_add_cat_description ($category) { 
    $cat_id=$category->term_id; $prod_term=get_term($cat_id,'product_cat'); 
    $description=trim($prod_term->description); 
    if(!empty($description))
        echo '<div class="shop_cat_desc">'.$description.'</div>'; 
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much!